# Why pingsender.Send Method causing problem in code and how to reduce IP scanning time using this function?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio

```
for (int i = 5; i <= 15; i++)
{
    string temp = string.Concat(base_IP, i.ToString());
    //await Task.Delay(1000);
    PingReply reply = pingsender.Send(temp, timeout, buffer, options);

    if (reply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
    {
        textbox_progress.Text = textbox_progress.Text + "Connected IP -> " + temp + "\n\r";
    }
    progressBar.Value++; 
}
textbox_progress.Text = textbox_progress.Text + "Scanning Complete " + "\n\r";
```

In the code segment , the progress-bar should increment with the increase in the value of variable '*i*'. However , it doesn't happen. The progress-bar get's updated all at once after the loop ends. If I comment out the IP scanning function and use the delay function, the progress-bar works properly. Can anyone help me to fix it?

Besides this, the scanning time is too long. I simply transmitted "*abcd*" to get ping. This small loop takes approximately 6 seconds to complete. The value of "timeout" is one [Although I'm confused if the "*pingsender.Send()*" function takes it as seconds or milliseconds]. I

Comment: use tasks, this will allow you to ping all devices at the same time rather than waiting for eaches reply.

Comment: "pingSender. Send("para1", para2)". "para1" is the destination URL, and "para2" is the ping time. You can achieve the effect of reducing the scan time by entering a smaller "para2".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ProgressBar` cannot be updated while your `for` loop is being executed on the same thread. This is impossible.

Use the asynchronous `SendPingAsync` method:

```
for (int i = 5; i <= 15; i++)
{
    string temp = string.Concat(base_IP, i.ToString());

    PingReply reply = await pingsender.SendPingAsync(temp, timeout, buffer, options);

    if (reply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
    {
        textbox_progress.Text = textbox_progress.Text + "Connected IP -> " + temp + "\n\r";
    }
    progressBar.Value++;
}
textbox_progress.Text = textbox_progress.Text + "Scanning Complete " + "\n\r";
```

> Although I'm confused if the "pingsender.Send()" function takes it as seconds or milliseconds

The `timeout` parameter specifies the maximum number of *milliseconds* (after sending the echo message) to wait for the ICMP echo reply message.